# I am creating chatting Application , getting this error _endCellAnimationsWithContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, chat

In chatting when I'm insert data in tableview cell I'm getting this error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[XHMessageTableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.21/UITableView.m:1582

I think problem in `messagedisplaykit` library

Please help me. 
THANK YOU.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a classic case where you don't update the data models before inserting the rows

Comment: @ROHAN After inserting 30 -40 rows then I'm getting crash

Comment: More data would be required to solve your query, some thing like how the delegate and datasource methods have been implemented

Comment: i am updating every thing but it is problem from messagedisplaylibrary  https://github.com/xhzengAIB/MessageDisplayKit/issues/297